# Ruby on Rails console moving rows in DB

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am making a webpage where I am iterating through a database of rows and it is order sensitive. It turns out that when I seeded the entries I made a mistake in one of the values in a row so I went to the console to change it. Once I entered 'project.save' it moved that row to the bottom of the table, thus ruining my order. How can I move the last row to the top of the table and push every other row down by one?

Comment: I think I know what you're doing wrong, but it would be helpful if you posed code demonstrating what you did that causes the problem, as well as the table structure of whatever table you're using. Please keep in mind that Stack Overflow users tend to be better at development than psychic powers. We can't know what's going on unless you show us.

Comment: It's not really code related. Basically I ran rails console to change an entry by doing project = Project.first. Then project.name = "new name". Afterwards, project.save. This caused the first row to be put into the final row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveRecord's default sort is by "Updated At". It isn't changing the position of the row in the database.

Just change the default scope to "id".

just add this line to your model, and the default will be your id.

```
default_scope { order(:id) }
```

For a better solution add a position to your model then sort by that

```
 default_scope { order(:position) }
```

This is the Rails 4 syntax, it is different for Rails 3 and 2.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: default scopes are not good. if you want to order a query, order that query -- default scopes will order *every* query the same.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use '[ORDER BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html)' clauses in your select statements. Without those, MySQL offers no guarantees that results will be in any order.